# Draw in a matrix.

Tags: matrices

Good afternoon

How to write picture below in matrix ?

Thanks for help

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the original image? It was surely done in TeX.

Comment: Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Not relevant to the question. Please, avoid teaching Sarrus' rule: if one knows it, good, but it is not easier than developing the determinant with other methods. And students will almost certainly try to apply it to 4×4 matrices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code from the wikipedia page on determinants:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[papersize={4.8cm, 2.6cm}, margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{tikzpicture}[semithick]
    \clip (-0.4, -0.3) rectangle (4.4, 2.3);

    \foreach \vert in {1, 2, 3} {
        \foreach \horz/\hnum in {1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/1, 5/2} {
            \node (a\vert-\horz) at (\horz - 1, 3 - \vert) {$a_{\vert\hnum}$};
        }
    }

    \draw
        (a1-1) -- (a2-2)  (a2-2) -- (a3-3)
        (a1-2) -- (a2-3)  (a2-3) -- (a3-4)
        (a1-3) -- (a2-4)  (a2-4) -- (a3-5);
    \draw [densely dashed]
        (a1-3) -- (a2-2)  (a2-2) -- (a3-1)
        (a1-4) -- (a2-3)  (a2-3) -- (a3-2)
        (a1-5) -- (a2-4)  (a2-4) -- (a3-3);

    \draw [thick, dotted] (2.5, -0.3) -- (2.5, 2.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```